# Filter file list in SmartGit

Tags: smartgit

In SmartGit I'm comparing two branches like described in [How to compare two branches/commits?](http://www.syntevo.com/doc/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6979721) I'm receiving the file list:

[image]

Then, how can I filter this files by name? Thanks.

Comment: This is currently not possible, but there is following RFE: https://smartgit.userecho.com/topics/224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only may *search* by name, but not *filter*. To search, put the focus into the Files table and start typing the name.

Comment: Yes, I see now. However searching only put you to first matching file, whereas  filtering would show you all matching files.